# Assets conflicting {url} tag

Tags: assets, members

At first I had this particular problem where Assets' {url} tag was returning "http://", *all the time for any file*.

```
{page_gallery}
    <li><a href="{url}" class="gallery"><img src="{url}"></a></li>
{/page_gallery}
```

Resulting in:

```
<li><a href="http://" class="gallery"><img src="http://"></a></li>
```

After hours of debugging, I've found that it's because that part of the template is wrapped in a `{exp:member:custom_profile_data}` where `{url}`actually means [the user's URL](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/#url).

I identified the problem, fine, but there is no way I can remove `{exp:member:custom_profile_data}` in this template. Is there any other way to access Assets' `{url}`? Namespace it someway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to use the var_prefix parameter.
{page_gallery var_prefix="image} {image:url} {/page_gallery}

And yet another would be just to use the Assets field as a single tag: {page_gallery}

Comment: That did it. Also was able to include image manipulations with `{image:url:small}`. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try the [shortcut tag](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/templating/field.html#shortcut-tags): `{page_gallery:url}`.

Comment: This outputted the right URL, but seemed to break my HTML after one iteration.